# How to Set column Formats In Excel File from C# Code

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ssis

I have a protected standard template excel sheet with formulas that I am loading SQL data to Excel through SSIS. While loading all int columns are convert to text format in an excel. Because of that formulas is not working until I double click each cell.

Or if I change that entire column format, right-click, select Format Cells and set the alignment or number format for the entire column, then it is calculating. I was wondering is there any way that I can change column format using C# code? or is there any better way to do this.

Comment: Without seeing the code you use to copy the data to excel its tough to be specific, but yes it is possible. Start with the `.NumberFormat` property...it may help you figure out where your code can be modified.

Comment: We load data to excel using SSIS. There is no existing script in there, other than sql statements. I thought of writing c# on SSIS script task to programatically change to column number format. But I am not sure am I thinking correctly or is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Excel Destination, and select "Show Advanced Editor". Change to the "Input and Output Properties" tab. Expand the "Excel Destination Input" and "External Columns". Click on the "Premium" column. The Data Type is probably "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]". Change it to an appropriate numeric type.